# Is there a way to println to enumerate and list words in a string?

Tags: java, arrays, string, counting

I'm trying to write a java program that will count the number of words in a declared sentence and then break the sentence up into words in order to list the words with numerical values and also display the words. I have the total count solved, but I can't seem to break up the words in the sentence and then list them chronologically. I can do it with characters, but not words.

I have explored both the Java Cookbook and other places to find a solution but I just do not understand it well enough. As I said, I can get the characters to count, and I can tally the words, but I can't get the individual words to print on separate lines with numerical values for their count in the string.

```
public class MySentenceCounter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String sentence = "This is my sentence and it is not great";

        String[] wordArray = sentence.trim().split("\\s+");
        int wordCount = wordArray.length;
        for (int i=0; i < sentence.length(  ); i++)
            System.out.println("Char " + i + " is " + sentence.charAt(i)); 
        //this produces the character count but I need it to form words, not individual characters.

        System.out.println("Total is " + wordCount + " words.");
    }
}
```

Expected results should look like:

```
1 This
2 is
3 my
4 sentence
5 and
6 it
7 is
8 not
9 great
Total is 9 words.
```

Comment: How about iterating over `wordArray` instead of the letters of `sentence`?

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over the `wordArray` variable you created rather than the original `sentence` string in your for loop:

```
public class MySentenceCounter {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String sentence = "This is my sentence and it is not great";
    String[] wordArray = sentence.trim().split("\\s+");
    // String[] wordArray = sentence.split(" "); This would work fine for your example sentence
    int wordCount = wordArray.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < wordCount; i++) {
      int wordNumber = i + 1;
      System.out.println(wordNumber + " " + wordArray[i]);
    }
    System.out.println("Total is " + wordCount + " words.");
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
1 This
2 is
3 my
4 sentence
5 and
6 it
7 is
8 not
9 great
Total is 9 words.
```

Comment: Splitting using " "-String will not work with multiple white spaces or tabs. I guess "\\s+" should be used instead.

Comment: Yeah, but the example string doesn't have multiple white spaces or extra white spaces at the start or end (I removed the `trim()` as well for the same reason). I'll change it back to what OP had.

Answer (score 0):

A bit more elegant solution using IntStream instead of a for-loop:

```
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class ExampleSolution
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String sentence = "This is my sentence and it is not great";

        String[] splitted = sentence.split("\\s+");
        IntStream.range(0, splitted.length)
                .mapToObj(i -> (i + 1) + " " + splitted[i])
                .forEach(System.out::println);

        System.out.println("Total is " + splitted.length + " words.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try avoiding too much complexity, the following does it just fine

```
public class MySentenceCounter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String sentence = "This is my sentence and it is not great";
        int ctr = 0;
        for (String str : sentence.trim().split("\\s+")) {
            System.out.println(++ctr + "" + str) ;
         } 
         System.out.println("Total is " + ctr + " words.");
    }
}
```